# Can't ask any more questions

Tags: support

Can anyone help me here? I have two questions being voted as off topic and too broad by some of the stack members. I have also emailed to stack exchange regarding this issue. But, they've asked me to put up my question here on meta. Can anyone tell me how and when can I start asking my question again. As presently I am not able to ask any question since so many days. I have asked the same members (who've put on my question on hold) to guide me how and when can I start asking my questions again, but I didn't got any reply. I've also edited my question as one of the guideline by stack exchange. But, again to no avail. I am still not able to ask any further question? Anyone who can help me out here please?

Comment: Hmm, I don't show your account as being blocked from posting. What happens when you try to post a new question?

Comment: It can happen that some questions get voted to be closed if they are duplicate, don't follow the guidelines or have already been answered in a similar way elsewhere. Stack Exchange is not a "ask anything" kind of place; it's a "I'm really stuck, I've search everywhere, what do I do" place. Don't take it personally if some of your questions got voted to be closed, there's a learning curve for everybody on how to answer and how to ask questions here ;) Why you cannot ask questions: Do you mean you literally cannot ask questions or do you mean your questions get voted to be closed?

Comment: @ go-meek : Hi. Thanks for replying back :) really agree to all you said. Every day and everywhere it's a learning. The problem I am facing is that I am not able to ask questions on graphicdesignstackexchange - I am getting a message as -           

Wait! Some of your past questions have not been well-received, and you're in danger of being blocked from asking any more.

For help formulating a clear, useful question, see: How do I ask a good question?

Also, edit your previous questions to improve formatting and clarity.

Comment: Can u pls tell me what should I do? As, I've already edited the questions also. But still I receive the same message whenever I am trying to ask a question from my graphicstackexchange account.

Comment: @JohnB- really appreciate your efforts. Thanks for the support :)

Answer (score 3):

Boldface mine:

> The problem I am facing is that I am not able to ask questions on graphicdesignstackexchange - I am getting a message as - Wait! Some of your past questions have not been well-received, and you're **in danger** of being blocked from asking any more. For help formulating a clear, useful question, see: How do I ask a good question? Also, edit your previous questions to improve formatting and clarity.

This is only a warning. You are not being blocked from asking (which explains [JohnB’s observation](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2774/cant-ask-any-more-questions#comment5891_2774)), but you might be blocked from asking if you keep asking low-quality questions. So, you can ask questions, but you should arguably put more effort into them as described in the warning and also the comments to this question.

Comment: It means I can ask any question now? obviously by taking required measurements?

Comment: If the warning you quoted is correct, yes, you should be able to ask questions now.

Comment: @ Wrzlprmft : Thanks a ton. Appreciate your efforts in helping me out.